# How to set multiple buttons and add them to a gridPane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, gridpane

for a GUI i have to set multiple buttons to a `GridPane`. For this i want to ask if there is a way to add multiple buttons in a Grid in a more elegant way than i do.
Here is an extractof my Code.

```
Button button0 =new Button("0");
    Button button1 =new Button("1");
    Button button2 =new Button("2");
    Button button3 =new Button("3");
    Button button4 =new Button("4");
    Button button5 =new Button("5");
    Button button6 =new Button("6");
    Button button7 =new Button("7");
    Button button8 =new Button("8");
    Button button9 =new Button("9");
    Button cancel = new Button("C");
    Button plus = new Button("+");
    Button minus = new Button("-");
    Button multiplicate = new Button("*");
    Button divide = new Button("/");
    Button equal = new Button("=");
```

For all of those buttons i have to set the row and column index separately.

```
root.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));
    GridPane.setConstraints(root, 4, 3);
    root.getChildren();
    root.add(label, 1, 1, 3, 1);
    root.add(button1, 2, 2);
    root.add(button2, 3, 2);
    root.add(button3, 4, 2);
    root.add(button4, 2, 3);
    root.add(button5, 3, 3);
    root.add(button6, 4, 3);
    root.add(button7, 2, 4);
    root.add(button8, 3, 4);
    root.add(button9, 4, 4);
    root.add(button0, 2, 5);
    root.add(cancel, 3, 5);
    root.add(plus, 5,2);
    root.add(minus, 5,3);
    root.add(multiplicate, 5, 4);
    root.add(divide, 5,5);
    root.add(equal, 4, 5);
```

I would be very greateful for any suggestions.

Comment: @Marko Jakob I suggest you to use FXML instead

Comment: Or, atleast make use of a loop for Button 0 to Button 9

Comment: OP should use scene builder for this, I also dislike using a GridPane for this, sine it seems to be a calculator, and some buttons (such as '+') are bigger than the others....  I would set up everything onto an AnchorPane in SceneBuilder, and then use Separators to split everything up.  Granted, you can make the buttons any size you want, it's just harder if you want to change sizes of some..  But could be a PITA to line up all the separators (just look at x,y though) for some people.

Comment: @Lasagna thanks for your comment i would prefer StackPane too but i wanted to set the buttons to look like a table. To imagine, the window should look like an calculator, indeed i wanted to programm a calculator and the problem is i do not know FXML.

Comment: Marco, , you want an `AnchorPane`  Please go search for "Scene Builder" and download it from Oracle's site.  This essentially is a GUI builder that creates FXML code from what you build,  that you can import into your code. You will need to learn about FXML Loading  and Controllers with JavaFX, but it is so much easier to work with Scene Builder when you have a lot of components.  IT's really not that hard at all, and you really do not need to know FXML yourself, just the loading of your files, and how to interact with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {

    int z1=0,y2=0,x=0; 

    @FXML
    GridPane gp;

    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(z1<4){    //add 4 buttons
            addButton();
            z1++;
        }   
    }   

    private void addButton() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final Button temp1=new Button("Button "+ y2);
        final int numberButton=y2;
        temp1.setId(""+y2);
        temp1.setText("whatever u want!!");
        temp1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                System.out.println("id("+temp1.getId()+")="+numberButton);
            }
        });
        gp.add(temp1, x, 0);  //x is column index and 0 is row index
        x++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use an FXML file as was suggested in a comment also.

But if you want to stick with Java code, you can do something like this (***my suggestion is still have an FXML file***):

*Main.java*

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            GridPane root = new GridPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());

            Button b = new Button();
            b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                }
            });

            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("0"), 2, 5);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("1"), 2, 2);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("2"), 3, 2);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("3"), 4, 2);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("4"), 2, 3);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("5"), 3, 3);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("6"), 4, 3);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("7"), 2, 4);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("8"), 3, 4);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("9"), 4, 4);

            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("C"), 3, 5, e -> System.out.println("C"));
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("+"), 5, 2, e -> System.out.println("+"));
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("-"), 5, 3);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("*"), 5, 4);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("/"), 5, 5);
            GridHelper.addToGrid(root, new Button("="), 4, 5);

            root.setPadding(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class GridHelper {

        static void addToGrid(GridPane grid, Node c, int col, int r) {
            grid.add(c, col, r);
        }

        static void addToGrid(GridPane grid, Node c, int col, int r, EventHandler<ActionEvent> event) {
            grid.add(c, col, r);
            addButtonEvent(c, event);
        }

        static void addToGrid(GridPane grid, Node c, int col, int r, int cs, int rs) {
            grid.add(c, col, r, cs, rs);
        }

        static void addToGrid(GridPane grid, Node c, int col, int r, int cs, int rs, EventHandler<ActionEvent> event) {
            grid.add(c, col, r, cs, rs);
            addButtonEvent(c, event);
        }

        static void addButtonEvent(Node button, EventHandler<ActionEvent> event) {
            if (button instanceof Button)
                ((Button) button).setOnAction(event);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

It just simply introduces a static class that exposes some static methods to add a `Node` to a `GridPane` to the specified position, and optionally set the spans (row/colum). If it is a `Button` you can add a press event also. Could be generalized further of course, it is just a sample for the exact question.

Also you could make a loop for `Button`s 0 - 9 (as it was proposed in the comment).